# Unable to extract sql.gz after successfully download

Tags: php, mysql

I write code for backup database. 
When I am trying to download file in sql.gz format that time it download successfully, But i can't extract it. It shows me this :-

> An error occured while loading the archive

Also each time its size is show only 620bytes but original .sql file size is large (greater than 1 MB)

```
  $path=$result_array['path'];
  $filename = basename($path);
  $full_path = base_url()."database_backup/";
  $len = filesize($full_path.$path);
  header("Content-Encoding: binary");
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header( "content-length: " . $len );
  header( "content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename );
  header("Expires: 0");
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Cache-Control: private");
  header("Pragma: public");
  ob_clean();
  $fp=fopen( $full_path, "r" );
  fpassthru( $fp );
  exit;
```

So please help me for solve this issue.

Comment: Please give me the solution.

Comment: `$len = filesize($full_path);` I think this line calculate wrong size. Please debug the size

Comment: Size is calculate completely using `$len = filesize($full_path);`

Comment: Please give me the solution

Answer (score 0):

There is a bad path in your script, compare these two lines of code from your question:

```
$len = filesize($full_path.$path);
```

and:

```
$fp=fopen( $full_path, "r" );
```

I assume the second should be:

```
$fp=fopen( $full_path . $path, "r" );
```

But, if you can, replace both $path with $filename to avoid arbitray file disclosure ($path could be something like "../../../../../../etc/passwd")